# How to "nail" an element to the bottom of scrollable window

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a scrollable side menu, where a specific text is supposed to stay at the right bottom.

The number of elements in this side menu can change - like clicking on an element will show all sub-elements - so the height of the menu will grow.

The maximum height is not limited in any way.

What I want - if the number of menu elements is small, and no scrolling is required, then the text should be bottom right.

If there are enough elements to make menu scrollable, it should appear after them all,  below everything else.

About like this:

[image]

I don't think anything about html should be shown here, it's just two divs.

```
<div className={styles.sideMenu}>
    // menu elements
</div>

<div className={styles.bottomElement}>
    // menu elements
</div>
```

I believe css is important here.

```
.sideMenu
{
    height: auto;
    position: sticky;
    bottom: 50px;
}

.bottomElement
{
  bottom: 2px;
  right: 32px;
  position:sticky;
  height: 34px;
}
```

For bottom element, bottom and right are a must. It must stay in this position.
I believe it also should have a fixed height.

But I don't know how I should define **position** values for both. I tried playing with absolute-relative-static-sticky-... but in all cases, either the element stays down if the menu is long, but goes up if the menu is short (just under option2 on leftmost example), or it stays on fixed position and overlaps with menu items.

Also I am not sure what should be the menu height. Should be be fixed with pixels/vh or percents? Or auto?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to what you mean regarding the height not being limited, but still having scrolling abilities; could you elaborate?

Comment: not sure how you get scrolling if you don't have a height for the outer element, but if you do set a height, then you can use a mixture of flex and position sticky for what you want: https://jsfiddle.net/0ero5dp8/1/

Comment: @Pete the code on your link solved the issue. Please post it as an answer, so I can upvote you and close the question. To others, I apologize, I couldn't find any better way to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment you can use flex with sticky positioning:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
}

.option-holder {
  line-height: 1.25rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 6.5rem;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.option-holder__top {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.option-holder__bottom {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="option-holder">
    <div class="option-holder__top">
      <div>Option</div>
      <div>Option</div>
    </div>
    <div class="option-holder__bottom">
      version
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="option-holder">
    <div class="option-holder__top">
      <div>Option</div>
      <div>Option</div>
      <div>Option</div>
      <div>Option</div>
    </div>
    <div class="option-holder__bottom">
      version
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="option-holder">
    <div class="option-holder__top">
      <div>Option</div>
      <div>Option</div>
      <div>Option</div>
      <div>Option</div>
      <div>Option</div>
      <div>Option</div>
      <div>Option</div>
      <div>Option 8</div>
    </div>
    <div class="option-holder__bottom">
      version
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```